# Licencing FOSS for profit

Tags: licensing, foss

Some projects are available under restrictive FOSS licenses (GPL or AGPL, for example) which preclude them from being used in proprietary projects. The developers can then sell separate commercial licenses which allow the code to be used in proprietary projects.

How common is this?

Examples I'm aware of:

[MySQL](http://www.fsf.org/blogs/rms/selling-exceptions)

[x264](http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/584)

[Cygwin](http://www.redhat.com/services/custom/cygwin/)

Comment: I've come across it a few times, also in ExtJS: http://www.sencha.com/products/license.php
I guess I wouldn't say it's common, but most things it is found in are supporting libraries or dependencies that might ultimately get linked in and could cause problems if they didn't allow commercial-compliant license terms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those licenses do not do what you think they do. Sadly, the GPL and similar licenses are widely misunderstood (even by the people that write them — by which I mean that the law often has a different idea of what given terms mean than the license writer).

The GPL does not preclude you from using it in proprietary projects.  Many proprietary projects have dependancies on FOSS licensed applications or libraries.  All it does is preclude you from trying to ship a binary without source, or to apply extra restrictions on those projects.

What's more, if you wrote the code in the first place, even if you publish it under the GPL, you can do anything you like, and make any exception you like.  You can even stop producing code in that license and produce only proprietary licensed versions.

However, to answer your question.  It's become quite "en vogue" for companies to publish a "community" version of a product and an "enterprise" version.  Examples include Vayatta, Alfresco, Flowplayer, and a whole bunch more.

The idea is that anyone that needs support will buy it anyways, and those that don't wouldn't buy your program anyways.  So it fosters a sort of "good will" even though it's really just a scheme.

Comment: It also (in my opinion) provides a nice way to support the original development effort without potentially suffering lawsuits which could cause a company to have to release its IP if they do something outside the spirit of the GPL.

Comment: GPLed code cannot be used in products that are proprietary in the usual sense.  It can be used in commercial products.

Comment: @David Thornley - That depends entirely on many things.  Can you directly copy code and place it within a proprietary application?  No.  However, there is much debate in the legal community over whether using it as as a shared library is the same thing (FSF says you can't do it, many lawyers say otherwise.. this is what I was getting at when I said that even the writers of the licenses don't always understand the legal interpretation of their licenses).  Many aspects of the GPL have yet to be tested in court to know for sure which way a judge would rule.

Comment: To be safe, assume that linking creates a derived work.  Some lawyers who've studied the issue say that's likely the case.  What I meant by commercial use is things like the software I'm working on now, on my other monitor.  It's proprietary, it's vital to our business, and it's not distributed.  We could use all sorts of GPLed code in there (as a matter of fact, we do have code under licenses that forbid us from selling it), perfectly legally and with Richard Stallman's blessing.

Answer (score 2):

The GPL license has a couple of clauses/definitions that are not clear outside the original scope (C programming) that give corporations heartburn.

1. If you *extend* a GPL project you are responsible to (a) advertise the fact, providing the GPL license to your users and (b) provide a copy of the source code to anyone who requests it.  **NOTE:** a request can be required to be done in writing, as opposed to making it available for download.
2. If you *link* to an GPL library you are *not* extending it, so the prior clause doesn't apply.  Problem is that *link* means different things depending on who you are talking to--for example what does it mean in an interpreted language like Ruby?

It's for the reason of potentially giving away corporate secrets that most corporations shy away from GPL based projects.  Additionally, there may be other legal/proprietary knowledge type risks that I'm not aware of.

Dual licensing is not uncommon.  It's a way of ensuring that the base product is always available, while providing value to people willing to pay for it.  It's also not uncommon to simply choose a FOSS license that doesn't contain the scary clauses such as the ASL, MIT license, or some variation.  It gives corporations much less heartburn to provide *attribution* than the source code.  In short it's better to say the product uses Apache Xerxes than to have to release the source code because it embedded a GPL'd XML parser.

---

**Additional background on American copyright**
Back in the 90's I attended a 2 week seminar that covered copyright law, as pertains to the entertainment industry.  That seminar was taught by one of the most pre-eminant lawyers focusing on the subject at that time: Al Schlessinger.  What follows is a brief summary of information from that seminar (I myself am not a lawyer, I'm just repeating information):

1. Copyright is real property, as in real-estate.  It can be bought, sold, bequeathed, and donated just as land can.
2. *Use* of copyrighted material is dictated by licenses, which in turn get their enforcement from contract law.  A license is a contract.
3. If the terms of the contract you are working under require you to turn over your copyright, you are in a "work for hire" situation.  This is how record companies can screw over newbie bands unless they know what to look for.  It is also RCA records screwed over Prince.
4. GPL does not convert the copyright to the original GPL'd project owners, but specifies terms for the original copyrighted work's *use*.  Essentially, that you would agree to expose your source code to those who asked for it.  You still retain the copyright to the derived work--but not the original work that it was derived from.

It is for this reason that when faced with the prospect of incorporating GPL or LGPL code/libraries into your commercial application that you vet everything with a lawyer who specializes in this type of work.  They exist, and my previous company used one to discover legal risks.  The lawyers did point out the potential problem points, which we had to relay to our client.

The tricky point for dual licensing is that the entity who is licensing the work must be able to prove that they have the only copyright for the work.  That is why when you become a committer on some of the larger umbrella organizations (GNU, Apache, etc.) you are required to sign an agreement that you turn over the copyright of that code to that organization.  When that condition is met, the organization can dual license, change the license model, or whatever they need to do at will.

It's because there is enough Fear, Uncertainty, and Doubt (FUD) surrounding the GPL on both sides of the equation that recently there's been more of a push to use corporate friendly licensing models.

Can the project you derived your work from cry foul and claim that you are in violation of the terms of the license?  Yes.  Will they?  Probably not.  That doesn't mean you should flagrantly violate its terms however.

Comment: Actually, the GPL does restrict linking to a library... which is the major difference between the GPL and LGPL.

Comment: There is no distinction between extending and not extending in the GPL.  Linking can constitute creating a derivative work.  Moreover, the GPL cannot force anybody to release source code.  That's not a legal remedy for copyright infringement.

Comment: Good distinction.  I've been through this process with a large client in the recent past.  If I recall correctly, linking to a plain GPL library would cause your application to automatically be required to be GPL'd.  Linking to the LGPL library would cause my second clause to come into play.  At least this would be the intent according to Richard Stallman's doctrine.

Comment: @David Thornley, the intent and purpose of the _Copyleft_ doctrine is to do exactly that.  By _agreeing_ to the terms of the GPL you are agreeing that you will be bound to releasing your derivative work source code.

Comment: _continued_...  Because the definitions of derivative work are muddy enough to cause heartburn for most corporate lawyers, they will always advise to stay away from such libraries/code.  Of course, if you are simply _using_ the project and not creating any derivative work based on the code you are probably free and clear legally.

Comment: @Berin:  There is the idea behind the GPL, and then there's the legal enforcement options.  The GPL has no enforcement provisions other than copyright law.  At least in the US, as I understand it, copyright violations can result in injunctions to not distribute the software, financial damages, and even criminal convictions.  Releasing somebody else's source code under a particular license is simply not something a copyright holder can enforce in court.

Comment: Copyright law gets it's enforcement options from contract law.  The GPL license is a form of contract that you can accept or reject.  This information is something I got from a seminar on the subject with Al Schlessinger teaching it.  Copyright is considered _real property_ (in the same way as real estate), and can be donated, bequeathed, sold, or relinquished.  If the license contract in essence says that you must relinquish your copyright to use the software, it will stand (see work for hire).  The GPL hasn't been tested in court, but no-one wants to be the guinee pig either.

Comment: @Berin Loritsch - Don't tell the FSF that, they keep insisting that the GPL is not a contract ;)

Comment: @Berin:  There's a difference between a contract and a license.  Last I heard, the few court cases that had looked at the distinction concluded it was a license, which is good because licenses are easier to enforce.  You will note that you can be sued for copyright violations without any existing contract, so your first sentence is obviously wrong.  Even if it were a contract, it would be a contract of adhesion, and the courts would be likely to find the publication requirement unconscionable and hence unenforceable.  Find another, more accurate, source.

Comment: There's been a lot of time since the 90's it could be things have gotten more complicated since that seminar. Copyrights are real property, and it goes without saying you can be sued for copyright violation if you use a copyrighted work without permission. Essentially contracts/licenses grant the terms and permission to _use_ a work, with the copyright law providing default provisions (i.e. no implied permission except in cases of education and worship [fair use act of 1984], etc.).

Comment: My end suggestion to get a lawyer work through the process doesn't change and is probably the most reasonable course of action--particularly considering all the conversation that this has generated.